# Generic method that output string based on the classes properties

Tags: c#

Having those 2 classes:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        strA1 = "A1";
        strA2 = "A2";
        strA3 = "A3";
    }

    public string strA1 { get; set; }
    public string strA2 { get; set; }
    public string strA3 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public B()
    {
        strB1 = "B1";
        strB2 = "B2";
    }

    public string strB1 { get; set; }
    public string strB2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to have a **single** method (probably override `toString()`) that will **generates information based on the number of properties** in these classes.

For example the result would be:

```
for Class A: "{\""A1\"",\""A2\"",\""A3\""}";  // {"A1","A2","A3"}
for Class B: "{\""B1\"",\""B2\""}";           // {"B1","B2"}
```

How Can be done in a generic way without writing specific code in each class?

Probably a Base class is the starting ... Please advise

Comment: Check these two questions started by me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752373/dynamically-create-members-of-interface
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635503/wiring-view-model-and-presenter-dynamically-by-convention-reflection

See if you can devise solution from there. If not, shout it and I might try to implement it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get type info and public properties value with Reflection. Here is an extension method:

```
public static string ConvertToString(this object obj)
{
   Type type = obj.GetType();
   var properties = 
         type.GetProperties()
             .Where(p => p.GetGetMethod() != null)
             .Where(p => !p.GetIndexParameters().Any())
             .Select(p => p.GetValue(obj, null))
             .Select(x => String.Format("\"{0}\"", (x == null) ? "null" : x));

   return String.Format("{{{0}}}", String.Join(", ", properties));
}
```

Usage:

```
string info = new A().ConvertToString();
```

Output:

```
{"A1","A2","A3"}
```

Comment: That makes sense. But should the parameter be an Base class or an interface?

Comment: @Boomer thats up to you - you can restrict usage of this extension method, otherwise it will be applicable to any object

Comment: @Boomer I updated code - now output is like you wanted in question, also for null values `null` will be displayed (you can change that)

Answer (score 1):

Look into reflection, to dynamically read all properties of the object. You can override ToString in the base class and use reflection to output all props.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var props = GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var prop in props)
        ...
}
```

(Untested, just to give you a general idea.)

Comment: I considered reflection but what the `GetType()` will return in a base class?

Comment: It will return the actual type, not the type of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a base class implementing such a method using reflection.

```
Type t = this.GetType()
foreach (PropertyInfo Info in t.GetProperties())
{
    // Property Name: Info.Name
    // Property Value: t.GetProperty(Info.Name).GetValue(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML serialization.